# AWS Elasticbeanstalk .ebextensions not deploying to /etc/httpd

Tags: php, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony4, ebextensions

In deploying a new app to EB, I found that the `.ebextensions` files that concern `httpd` are not being deployed to `/etc`.

The files as such are the same as the ones from another app, like this one:

/.ebextensions/cors.config

```
 files:
/etc/httpd/conf.d/cors.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    content: |
        SetEnvIf Origin "^https?:\/\/localhost:[0-9]+.*|https?:\/\/127.0.0.1[:[0-9]+]?|https:\/\/mywebsite.com" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
        Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type, authorization"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
        Header add Access-Control-Max-Age "86400"
```

Otherwise are identical to the ones provided by AWS in [this depository](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/php/https-redirect-php.config)

Note that I do have a file that is correctly deployed to `/etc/php.d`, so it would seem that the `.ebextensions` deployment overall is working.

The issue seems to be related to Apache. When configuring the environment I did notice a new selection to be made between Apache and Nginx. I did select Apache.

I am a bit out of ideas at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create this directory structure in your application root `.platform/httpd/conf.d/` and put your apache config files in it.

Refer to this article for more info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Answer (score 0):

I lost two days trying to discover this!
It happens because the official tutorial/docummentation still not mentioning that 'Configurations files' structure has changed in Amazon Linux 2. As we can see, the guide shows us a wrong path for '.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf' in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html.

The new servers are coming with  **Amazon Linux 2**, and therefore 'httpd' folder should stay outside '.ebextensions', in a new root hidden folder called '.platform'

If The migration guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html, and/or changes in Ambient related folder structure, was referenced in tutorial should avoid this doubt. I leave a feedback to AWS to included it.